# Создать уникальные значения

Tags: php

Есть цифры от 1 до 73. Нужно из этого набора выбрать только 5 случайных, но чтобы они не повторялись.

```
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  echo rand(1,73).' - ';
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 17-43-47-5-5- это общи вид того, что нужно на выходе?

Comment: Это вид, то что в данном коде цифры повторяются и в данном случае  повторилось две 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как один из вариантов:

```
$result = [];

while (count($result) < 5) {
    $n = rand(1,73);
    if (!in_array($n, $result)) {
        $result[] = $n;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function rand_numbers($min, $max, $count){
    $num = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($num);
    return array_slice($num, 0, $count);
}
print_r(rand_numbers(1, 73, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$random = [];
$x = 5;
for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
    $r = rand(1,73);
    (!in_array($r, $random)) ? $random[] = $r : $x++;
}
$random = implode($random, '-');
```

Comment: кто постоянно минусует рабочие ответы? и не стыдно же :)

Comment: в каком месте оно рабочее? по условию повторений быть не должно. у вас они есть. ваш ответ - полностью скопированный вопрос. просто вместо вывода чисел, вы их копите в массиве.

Comment: во блин, проверку забыл)